# How to develop Native Module for React-Native rapidly?

Tags: react-native

I use Atom Editor and GenyMotion on Windows 10 to develop a native module.

However, modifying and trying code are take long time because of building (`react-native run-android`) and starting (`react-native start`) processes at every single time.

I wonder is there another way to develop in less time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an SSD instead of an HDD provides an amazing benefit.

So, I've switch to using an SSD on a new laptop.

Do not look for another solution.

React-native makes a lot of disk operation with a lot of modules when it working.

It tries to access a lot of file. Using SSD is the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up the build process a little bit by running Gradle Daemon. But, You can't avoid the `react-native run-android`. Recompilation is mandatory if you are changing the JAVA code. But, You don't have to re-run `react-native start` again after the recompilation most of the times.

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't understand that how can I avoid to run the command of `react-native start`. If I run start command separately the whole directory is locked by react-native process. Am I wrong

Comment: You don't have to stop the package manager at all. You can just run `react-native run-android`, It will not stop the package manager. So, you don't have to start again.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. I think that's pretty useful. Thanks again..

Comment: However if I re-build the app, throws an error as  `Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > outDexFolder must be a folder`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you add any new packages in NPM? If you install any new packages, then the restart of package manager is mandatory. For outDexFolder issue, Check the package which you added in NPM last.

Comment: No I didn't actually. I just add a new Native-Module which I wrote. Thanks again. But I shouldn't accept the answer for others.

Comment: Check the first answer in this link https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/49ntk6/native_component_for_rctmap_does_not_exist/